# Stagefright - Streaming Playback Architecture

Tags: android, streaming, stagefright

I am going through the streaming playback use case in `Android` `Stagefright` and quite not clear about the architecture and implementations.

I am requesting readers/experts to explain about the major components which are responsible for streaming use case. I heard about `ACodec` is being employed instead of `OMXCodec` to realize streaming playback.

What is the extra implementations/features supported by `ACodec` and why `Stagefright` didn't reuse `OMXCodec`.

Could you please point me the important links in `Stagefright` code.

Comment: For cache realted and pause-resume related topics, I would recommend you to post a different question as the context would be specific to streaming scenarios.

Comment: The question is modified as per your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For streaming, there are different scenarios handled differently by the `Stagefright` framework. Broadly, there are 2 players and corresponding factories viz., `StagefrightPlayer` and `NuPlayer`.

`StagefrightPlayer` is employed as a default player, where as `NuPlayer` is employed for [`rtsp`, `m3u8` (`MP3` playlist), `sdp`](http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r2/xref/frameworks/av/media/libmediaplayerservice/MediaPlayerFactory.cpp#208) playback as implemented in the `NuPlayerFactory`.

`NuPlayer` could also be employed when a [system property is set](http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r2/xref/frameworks/av/media/libmediaplayerservice/MediaPlayerFactory.cpp#65) to employ the same as the default player.

`StagefrightPlayer` internally creates [`AwesomePlayer` which handles `http`/`https` and `Widevine`](http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r2/xref/frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/AwesomePlayer.cpp#2189) streaming too.

Now coming to `ACodec` and `OMXCodec` are pretty close to each other as they abstract an `OMX` component. `ACodec` is the underlying implementation of `MediaCodec` which is a modular interface exposed by Android in the recent releases.

One point of difference though is that some new features such as [prepending `SPS`/`PPS` to `IDR` in case of `Miracast`](http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r2/xref/frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/ACodec.cpp#1062), [`Adaptive Playback`](http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r2/xref/frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/ACodec.cpp#1124) etc are included only in `ACodec` and not in `OMXCodec`.

Comment: Hi Ganesh, NuPlayerFactory is creating NuPlayerDriver in turn it creates ALooper and NuPlayer. Could you please brief about ALooper and what does it do. I can see all the implementations in Nuplayer are invoking AMessage calls e.g as: new AMessage(kWhatSourceNotify, id()); I am not sure how does it trigger NuPlayer::onMessageReceived(). In case of memory playback, Awesome player creates OMXCodec and extractor. Could you please explain how does it happen in case of
streaming playback?

Comment: @SatishNagireddy.. To keep topics specific, I would request you to kindly breakdown your comment into multiple different questions as one question on entire player engine may not be such a good idea

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion. I will break down my question and post them as different questions.